# MAC Terminal - MySQL query with argument toward the end?

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

Sometimes I have to run multiple queries (one after another) with slightly different arguments so I can quickly compare results. I use the up arrow to populate the Terminal input field with the most recent query and then use the left arrow key many times to get to the one place where I need to change the value. I was wondering if there was a way to specify a placeholder in the query and then have the argument toward the end of the query, so it's quicker to change?

As a side question, is there a way to move the cursor faster e.g. move it every 10 characters instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SET @PARAM = "whatever";
INSERT INTO WHATEVER (Name) VALUES (@PARAM);
```

That way you can scroll back two lines and just replace the variable.